# Generating sub data frame based on a value in an column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following data frame in pandas. Now I want to generate sub data frame if I see a value in Activity column. So for example, I want to have data frame with all the data with Name `A` IF Activity column as value `3` or `5`.

```
Name    Date           Activity
A       01-02-2015       1
A       01-03-2015       2
A       01-04-2015       3
A       01-04-2015       1
B       01-02-2015       1
B       01-02-2015       2
B       01-03-2015       1
B       01-04-2015       5
C       01-31-2015       1
C       01-31-2015       2
C       01-31-2015       2
```

So for the above data, I want to get
`df_A` as

```
Name    Date           Activity
A       01-02-2015       1
A       01-03-2015       2
A       01-04-2015       3
A       01-04-2015       1
```

`df_B` as

```
B       01-02-2015       1
B       01-02-2015       2
B       01-03-2015       1
B       01-04-2015       5
```

Since Name `C` does not have `3` or `5` in the column `Activity`, I do not want to get this data frame.

Also, the names in the data frame can vary with each input file.

Once I have these data frame separated, I want to plot a time series.

Comment: Often, if is not necessary nor efficient to create more variables. You can [group](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the data you want and then [look](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for a given condition, and, finally, [plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#api-dataframe-plotting) a time series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to create a sub dataframe for each Name with an Activity value of 3 or 5.

```
active_names = df[df.Activity.isin([3, 5])].Name.unique().tolist()
dfs = {name: df.loc[df.Name == name, :] for name in active_names}

>>> dfs['A']
  Name        Date  Activity
0    A  01-02-2015         1
1    A  01-03-2015         2
2    A  01-04-2015         3
3    A  01-04-2015         1

>>> dfs['B']
  Name        Date  Activity
4    B  01-02-2015         1
5    B  01-02-2015         2
6    B  01-03-2015         1
7    B  01-04-2015         5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) dataframe by column `Name`, [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) custom function `f` and then select dataframes `df_A` and `df_B`:

```
print df
   Name       Date  Activity
0     A 2015-01-02         1
1     A 2015-01-03         2
2     A 2015-01-04         3
3     A 2015-01-04         1
4     B 2015-01-02         1
5     B 2015-01-02         2
6     B 2015-01-03         1
7     B 2015-01-04         5
8     C 2015-01-31         1
9     C 2015-01-31         2
10    C 2015-01-31         2


def f(df):
    if ((df['Activity'] == 3) | (df['Activity'] == 5)).any():
        return df

g = df.groupby('Name').apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
df_A = g.loc[g.Name == 'A']
print df_A
  Name       Date  Activity
0    A 2015-01-02         1
1    A 2015-01-03         2
2    A 2015-01-04         3
3    A 2015-01-04         1

df_B = g.loc[g.Name == 'B']
print df_B
  Name       Date  Activity
4    B 2015-01-02         1
5    B 2015-01-02         2
6    B 2015-01-03         1
7    B 2015-01-04         5

df_A.plot()
df_B.plot()
```

In the end you can use [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) - more [info](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot)

EDIT:

If you want create dataframes dynamically, use can find all unique values of column `Name` by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
for name in g.Name.drop_duplicates():
    print g.loc[g.Name == name]

      Name       Date  Activity
0    A 2015-01-02         1
1    A 2015-01-03         2
2    A 2015-01-04         3
3    A 2015-01-04         1
  Name       Date  Activity
4    B 2015-01-02         1
5    B 2015-01-02         2
6    B 2015-01-03         1
7    B 2015-01-04         5
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps me a lot. How do I generate df'A' or df'B' dynamically based on the 'name' column values once I know that requiered activity is there in the 'Activity' column?

Comment: I try to add it to answer. You can accept my answer and vote up too. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks.